# Make it possible (more easily discoverable?) to view jobs in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, jobs, ios-app

I get "suggested jobs" in the iOS app, but I don't see an easy way to fully access StackOverflow Jobs with full search, etc. There's not an option in the other sites' entries either, at least not under careers.